# Eclipse Window Builder JFrame Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I've been having a problem with viewing my JFrames recently. I was able to view them just fine in the Design panel of Window Builder not too long ago, and now all that I see is just the JFrame options to minimize, maximize, or close the screen. Everything else around it is white. I am using a card layout on Juno Eclipse.

However, when I run the program, the small JFrame options to minimize, maximize, or exit appear. I am able to maximize my program and run it. The problem is that I can't seem to see where my labels or buttons are in design mode. Instead I just see white, which makes it difficult to do any editing.

This would be a lot easier if I was able to post pictures.

Comment: Why can't you post pictures? Use the image button in the editor to select a file from your computer

Answer (score 0):

The problem you describe happens when you change the auto-generated code too much by hand. For example, adding too many method calls, or especially changing constructors, etc causes it to lose its ability to render the preview. This is one of the reasons I avoid using WindowBuilder as much as possible, because this is a known bug and as far as I know there is not a fix. I'm sorry for being the bearer of bad news, but unless you can find the added code that caused it to complain, and manipulate it a bit, you may be out of luck. The trick to getting WindowBuilder to work for you is to keep as close to the structure of the auto-generated code as possible.